# I need to have a join on OR condition

Tags: mysql, join

So I have a join for e.g lets say

```
SELECT a.id FROM tableA as a 
  JOIN tableB as b on a.id=b.aid 
  JOIN tableC as c on (c.aid != a.id or ???) and a.name = 'fedex' and b.user = 'employee' and c.enabled=true
```

??? being if c does not contain that a.id I would still like the result to contain that result

I tried left outer join but that didn't do the trick

By the way even if I have one single record in the table c then this query works fine. If the table c is empty that's when the query fails.

Comment: Have you considered a `RIGHT JOIN`?

Comment: Isn't it just `LEFT JOIN`?  Or is `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the same thing?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Its pretty much the same in this case. And I have tried both of them as well.

Comment: What results are you seeing with a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @CollinD Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: @CollinD And no right join wont  make a difference.

Comment: please, paste your real query!

Answer (score 1):

You are describing what a `LEFT JOIN` does.  So, did you try this?

```
SELECT a.id
FROM tableA a JOIN
     tableB b
     on a.id = b.id LEFT JOIN
     tableC c
     on c.id = a.id;
```

Of course, your query is so simple that the you don't even seem to need `TableC`.  This would return the same set of `a.id`:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT b.ID FROM tableB b)
```

The only difference is that your version might produce duplicates.

Comment: I tried that and it works fine when there is data in the table c otherwise nothing is returned.

Comment: i.e. when tableC is empty it does not return any rows

Comment: The first query should return rows even when `tableC` is empty.  Something else must be going on, such as a `where` clause you didn't include in the question.

Comment: let me post the whole query

Comment: Take a look at the query, except for table names everything else is same.

Comment: @john.p.doe . . . If you have a `left join` to `tableC`, then including the `join` cannot reduce the number of rows in the result set, regardless of whether the condition ever evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id FROM tableA as a 
JOIN tableB as b on a.id = b.aid and b.user = 'employee' 
LEFT JOIN tableC as c on c.aid != a.id and a.name = 'fedex' and c.enabled=true
```